# Missing argument 2 for Illuminate when using command line to create controller

Tags: command-line, laravel, laravel-4, code-generation

I am trying to create controller using the command line in laravel but when i SSH to my server and try to run the laravel CLI command `php artisan controller:make AboutController` 
or even any other command like : `php artisan list`

I always get this message :

```
{
"error":
  {
    "type":"ErrorException",
    "message":"Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::controller(), called in \/home1\/jokira\/public_html\/laravel\/bootstrap\/compiled.php on line 3155 and defined","file":"\/home1\/jokira\/public_html\/laravel\/bootstrap\/compiled.php","line":4379
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Try running a composer update and then post what happens next.

Comment: I'd remove the file bootstrap/compiled.php and try again. It's autogenerated so you don't risk anything removing it, and it looks like it may well be the error.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you add some wrong routes to app/routes.php just like what I did.
I add some temp route like this:

```
    //user routes
    Route::get('/login');
    Route::post('/login');
    Route::get('/reg');
    Route::post('/reg');
```

And I got the same errors as you .

After I deleted this lines , all works fine now.

Wish can help you .

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the path of the route for your controller.

This is wrong example:
`Route::controller('AuthController');`

And this is the correct one:
`Route::controller('/auth', 'AuthController');`